# Make keyboard slide in from the bottom on push with custom transition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

By default, the keyboard will slide in from the right when you call `becomeFirstResponder` from within `viewWillAppear` while the view is being slid in from the right (push transition).

However, I have setup a custom transition which means a view slides in from the bottom. But the keyboard still slides in from the right.

I can get around it by waiting until the view is displayed and the transition is complete, but I would prefer the keyboard is shown immediately on push.

Comment: I had a similar problem , so I called becomeFirstResponder in viewDidLoad. The keyboard was up as soon as the transition was complete.

Comment: @NavinDev Thanks, but it still shows from the right.